CSS Modules in next aliases doesn't autocomplete class names if css file is outside component folder
I Use VSCode with CSS Modules extension for NextJS project with path aliases. Autocompletion for files working fine, but the classNames itself only show up if importing file without path aliases.
for example the
import styles from "./Main.module.css";
will show up autocomplete variants:

but the
import commonStyles from "@styles/common.module.css"; will show nothing, it doesn't load anything about file, only global autocomplete hints

I use latest version of NextJS, vscode and extensions.
Here is my tsconfig and next config:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "plugins": [
            {
                "name": "next"
            }
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"],
            "@styles/*": ["./src/shared/UI/styles/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    webpack(config) {
        const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test?.test?.(".svg"));
        config.module.rules = [
            ...config.module.rules.filter((rule) => rule !== fileLoaderRule),
            { ...fileLoaderRule, exclude: /\.svg$/i },
            {
                ...fileLoaderRule,
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                resourceQuery: {
                    ...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery,
                    not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /component/],
                },
            },
            { test: /\.svg$/i, issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/, use: "@svgr/webpack", resourceQuery: /component/ },
        ];
        return config;
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

If anybody had face this issue too and resolve it, please help

I resolve this issue installing a VS Code Extension called Css Modules
Nombre: CSS Modules
ID: clinyong.vscode-css-modules
Descripción: Visual Studio Code extension for CSS Modules
Versión: 0.5.1
Editor: clinyong
Vínculo de VS Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=clinyong.vscode-css-modules

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Hi Juan, I happened to stumble upon your answer when I was looking for an extension to help me. It did help me, however, this does not answer the question because the individual is not looking for an extension. They already have stated they are using the code extension CSS Modules. Please review the original question again and see if you left something out by mistake. :)

I Already use this extension, and it doesn't solve my problem

@Juan Antonio Marquez, awesome, bro! Thank you! I confirm it's giving me auto-completion in my Next.js app ^_^
